# OpenVPN: Forward one ip from client lan to server

Tags: networking, openvpn

My setup looks as following:

- Server (ubuntu server) with public ip address `1.2.3.4` acting as OpenVPN server
- RaspberryPi (raspbian) connected to the OpenVPN server with address `10.8.0.6` in OpenVPN network and local address in physical network `192.168.178.36`
- "Lan-Client" is in the same physical network as the raspberry pi with the local address `192.168.178.56`
- "Client" is in the same OpenVPN network as the raspberry pi with the address `10.8.0.10`

With my current setup, the "client" and the raspberry pi are successfully connect with the openvpn server and can communicate with each other.
Now I want to forward the "lan-client" to the openvpn network using the raspberry pi as a router, so each client connected to the openvpn server can access it.

I can't install OpenVPN on the "lan-client", nor can I do some port forwarding to it or change any configuration at all.

Is this even possible with OpenVPN? And if so, how can I do that? I only want to forward this specific ip and not all clients in the raspberry pis lan.

My current configs look like this:

**server.conf**

```
port  1194
proto udp
dev   tun

ca   /etc/certs/ca.crt
cert /etc/certs/server.crt
key  /etc/certs/server.key

dh   /etc/certs/dh4096.pem

cipher AES-256-CBC

server    10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
keepalive 10 120
client-to-client

ifconfig-pool-persist /etc/openvpn/ipp.txt
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd

persist-key
persist-tun

status     /var/log/openvpn/status.log
log        /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
log-append /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log

verb 3
```

**ipp.txt** (server)

```
client-rpi,10.8.0.4
```

**ccd/client-rpi** (server)

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.6 10.8.0.1
```

**client.conf** (raspberry pi)

```
client
dev     tun
proto   udp
remote  1.2.3.4 1194

resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun

ca   /etc/certs/ca.crt
cert /etc/certs/client-rpi.crt
key  /etc/certs/client-rpi.key

cipher AES-256-CBC

remote-cert-tls server

verb 3
```

Even though I only want to route one ip address, I've already followed some guides online to route the complete lan. In order to do that, I added

```
route 192.168.178.0 255.255.255.0
```

to the **server.conf** and

```
iroute 192.168.178.0 255.255.255.0
```

to the **ccd/client-rpi** config. When I try to ping `192.168.178.20` for example on the server, I get a 100% packet loss (no answer). On the raspberry pi it looks like this:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i tun0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
09:39:09.863118 IP 10.8.0.1 > 192.168.178.20: ICMP echo request, id     19467, seq 1, length 64
09:39:10.869903 IP 10.8.0.1 > 192.168.178.20: ICMP echo request, id 19467, seq 2, length 64
09:39:11.878093 IP 10.8.0.1 > 192.168.178.20: ICMP echo request, id 19467, seq 3, length 64
```

When I ping the same address but from the raspberry pi (which is in the same physical network as the target) everything works fine, as expected, so it's not the targets firewall who drops the requests.

My guess is, that the raspberry pi receives the ping requests and forwards it, but the target `192.168.178.20` doesn't know how to respond. The problem is, as already mentioned, I can't change the routing table nor other settings on that device. I only have access to the server and the raspberry pi. Is my understanding right, and is there a solution that would work out? Or is it just my misconfiguration and misunderstanding? It could also be a problem on the raspberry pi with routes, but I have no idea on how to fix that.

Comment: You could look at using IP Tables to nat connections coming from the VPN to the raspi IP range, that'd allow clients on the lan side to reply to something that appeared to be 'local' to them - avoiding having to add routes.

Comment: @djsmiley2k Thanks, as I only needed like 3 ports I managed to forward them through the raspberry pi using nat rules and iptables. And the server can access the raspberry pi through the openvpn network.

Comment: Awesome :) Wanna write that up as an answer and self accept? Self-documentation might help someone else in the future :)